# Why is the markup of this code invalid?

Tags: html

I was writing a `html` code and I wanted to **close** all the code it into a **single div**. When I placed it into a single `div`, it gave me an error that my markup is **invalid** (showing that the closing `div` tag is **invalid**.) Now I am amazed how can it be invalid. Please help me out. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
            <iframe width="350" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/P3weDRMemD8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <form style="border:3px;text align.center;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit=                "window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=financeyoga/UPqT', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">

            <input type="text" style="width:140px;padding:10px;" name="email"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="financeyoga/UPqT" name="uri"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><br>
            <input style="padding:10px;" type="submit" value="Submit Email Address" />
            <img style="position:relative;top:325px; left:10px;" src="http://financeyoga.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/follow.png" width="143" height="64" border="0" usemap="#Map">
            <map name="Map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="5,18,33,44" href="www.twitter.com" target="_blank" alt="twitter">
            <area shape="rect" coords="57,16,87,46" href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank" alt="facebook">
            <area shape="rect" coords="107,16,137,46" href="plus.google.com" target="_blank" alt="google plus">
            </map>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: I’m always amazed when the computer tells me my code’s wrong too. I do find that the computer’s usually right though.

Comment: @TrevorSenior: Thanks. I will use that from now to validate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't closed your `form` tag.

Comment: +1 Beat me by about 2 seconds :) I'd also suggest OP uses http://validator.w3.org/check as it explicitly says `Line 23, Column 6: End tag div seen, but there were open elements.`

Comment: I didn't use a validator, but that's definitely the way to go - especially if there's a lot of markup.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it is missing `</form>` tag.